# Invalid command 'host', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. If i add .htaccess text: Host: vash_site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Invalid command 'host'**, perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

*.htaccess*

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow:
Host: vash_site.ru
```

Comment: You seem to confuse things here ... A ".htaccess" file, so a distributed configuration file, is part of the configuration of the apache http server. The content you implemented and posted has nothing to do with such a file. That content looks like the content of a "robots.txt" file. Both files serve completely different purposes. The question is what you are actually trying to do here ...

Comment: `User-agent` and `Disallow` should also be throwing up errors if you are putting those in a `.htaccess` file?! (_Aside:_ Yandex no longer appears to support the `Host:` directive in `robots.txt`. Reference: https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html)

Comment: tanks all
i forget robots.txt )